# Recursive default argument reference

Tags: r

Can anyone explain me what is wrong in this code below. What I thought I am doing here is

- a declaration of a global variable `a=5`
- a definition of a function `fun` which takes one argument which defaults to the aforementioned global variable `a`

And when I call `fun()` without any parameters the local variable `a` becomes a copy of the global variable `a` and at any point in the function code it takes precedence over the global `a` (unless I specifically use `get("a", envir=parent.frame)`)

But I must be wrong. Why isn't it allowed?

```
> a = 5
> fun = function(a=a) { a + 1 }
> fun(4)
[1] 5
> fun()
Error in fun() : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Comment: Please take a moment to [read the formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: eventually you wanted to code something like   
`fun <- function(a=environment(fun)$a) { a + 1 }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And when I call `fun()` without any parameters the local variable a becomes a copy of the global variable `a`

No: default arguments are evaluated inside the scope of the function. Your code is similar to the following code:

```
fun = function(a) {
    if (missing(a)) a = a
    a + 1
}
```

This makes the scoping clearer and explains why your code doesn’t work.

Note that this is *only* true for default arguments; arguments that are explicitly passed are (of course) evaluated in the scope of the caller.

Comment: Do I understand correctly what you say is that BOTH LHS and RHS of the assignment *a = a* are evaluated inside the scope of the function?

Comment: @Mat Yes. As for any normal assignment.